# How do you write a Django query where the condition if a COUNT of related items?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, count, foreign-keys

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have these two models, related to one another through a foreign key ...

```
class Website(models.Model):
    objects = WebsiteManager()
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Article(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlesite')
    title = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    url = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now)
```

I want to write a Django query that returns the web sites who have more than 100 articles tied to them.  In PostGres, I can write this query

```
select w.id, count(*) FROM website w, article a where w.id = a.website_id group by w.id;
```

but I'm unclear how to do this with a Django query.  How do I write a query where the condition if a COUNT function?

**Edit:**

I modified my query to add a condition ...

```
qset = Website.objects.annotate(articlesite_count=Count('articlesite')).filter(
                         articlesite__edited_date__null=True,
                         articlesite_count__gte=100)
```

but now this results in the error

```
Unsupported lookup 'null' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use annotate then filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)

```
from django.db.models import Count

Website.objects.annotate(articlesite_count=Count('articlesite')).filter(articlesite_count__gte=100)
```

---

### UPDATE-1

```
from django.db.models import Count

Website.objects.filter(articlesite__edited_date__isnull=True).annotate(
    articlesite_count=Count('articlesite')).filter(
    articlesite_count__gte=100)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Perhaps I shoud ask a separate question, but do you know how I add an additional condition into my "filter"?  I added an extra condition (specified in my question edit), but now this results in a "Unsupported lookup 'null' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted." error.

Comment: Can you add that date field ?

Comment: and What you mean by `high_article_count` ?

Comment: Hi @JPG, You got it -- I added the date field definition into the model in my question.  "high_article_count" is a number but for clarity, I just updated my question to include the number instead of the weirder variable name.